# Whenever i open a man page in ubuntu, i see this warning

Tags: linux, ubuntu, locale, manpage

When I type any command related to man pages I get this.

```
"man: can't set the locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct"
```

Please help me with this. Thanks

Comment: What do you get if you type `locale`?  Also, what do you get when you type `locale -a`?  Post back the results.

Comment: ok...got that...it tells us about lang in the currnt envrmnt..and thanks

Comment: Okay, so did you solve your problem? If not, can you post (edit your question) with the results from those commands.

Comment: yea  got it solved... "sudo locale-gen" when i typed in this everything was solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typing the command `locale -a` will show which locales are available on your system.

Typing the command `locale` will show how your locale variables are currently assigned.

See [this wiki page for an explanation of locale on Ubuntu including how to set it correctly](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale)